# Read stored procedure select results into pandas dataframe

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Given:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure
    @Param INT
AS
    SELECT Col1, Col2
    FROM Table
    WHERE Col2 = @Param
```

I would like to be able to use this as:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

query = 'EXEC my_procedure @Param = {0}'.format(my_param)
conn = pyodbc.connect(my_connection_string)

df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

But this throws an error:

```
ValueError: Reading a table with read_sql is not supported for a DBAPI2 connection. Use an SQLAlchemy engine or specify an sql query
```

SQLAlchemy does not work either:

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(my_connection_string)
df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

Throws:

```
ValueError: Could not init table 'my_procedure'
```

I can in fact execute the statement using `pyodbc` directly:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)
```

Is there a way to send these procedure results directly to a DataFrame?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? And can you try to use `pd.read_sql_query` instead of `read_sql`? (there was a bug in `read_sql` regarding executing stored procedures)

Answer (score 11):

Use **read_sql_query()** instead.

Looks like @joris (+1) already had this in a comment directly under the question but I didn't see it because it wasn't in the answers section.

Use the SQLA engine--apart from SQLAlchemy, Pandas only supports SQLite. Then use **[read_sql_query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query)** instead of read_sql(). The latter tries to auto-detect whether you're passing a table name or a fully-fledged query but it doesn't appear to do so well with the 'EXEC' keyword. Using read_sql_query() skips the auto-detection and allows you to explicitly indicate that you're using a query (there's also a read_sql_table()).

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

query = 'EXEC my_procedure @Param = {0}'.format(my_param)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(my_connection_string)
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
```

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me after added `SET NOCOUNT ON` thanks @CRAFTY DBA

```
sql_query = """SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC db_name.dbo.StoreProc '{0}';""".format(input)

df = pandas.read_sql_query(sql_query , conn)
```

Comment: I had to do this as well. In order to get my query to work i had to create the string with triple quotes using single quotes around my stored procedure's variables. Looked like this `"""EXEC sProcedure 'variable1', 'variable2'"""`

Answer (score 7):

https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/StoredProcedures

I am not a python expert, but SQL Server sometimes returns counts for statement executions.  For instance, a update will tell how many rows are updated.

Just use the 'SET NO COUNT;' at the front of your batch call.  This will remove the counts for inserts, updates, and deletes.

Make sure you are using the correct native client module.

Take a look at this stack overflow example.

It has both a adhoc SQL and call stored procedure example.

[Calling a stored procedure python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419276/calling-a-stored-procedure-python)

Good luck

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT ON` unfortunately doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Adding SET NOCOUNT ON at the start of my stored procedure worked.  Thanks.  Also, I tried adding "SET NOCOUNT ON; " to the start of my query and that worked as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using ODBC syntax for calling stored procedures (with parameters instead of string formatting) works for loading dataframes using pandas 0.14.1 and pyodbc 3.0.7. The following examples use the [AdventureWorks2008R2 sample database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/59211).

First confirm expected results calling the stored procedure using pyodbc:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}', server='ServerInstance', database='AdventureWorks2008R2', trusted_connection='yes')
sql = "{call dbo.uspGetEmployeeManagers(?)}"
params = (3,)
cursor = connection.cursor()
rows = cursor.execute(sql, params).fetchall()
print(rows)
```

Should return:

```
[(0, 3, 'Roberto', 'Tamburello', '/1/1/', 'Terri', 'Duffy'), (1, 2, 'Terri', 'Duffy',
'/1/', 'Ken', 'Sánchez')]
```

Now use pandas to load the results into a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql=sql, con=connection, params=params)
print(df)
```

Should return:

```
   RecursionLevel  BusinessEntityID FirstName    LastName OrganizationNode  \
0               0                 3   Roberto  Tamburello            /1/1/
1               1                 2     Terri       Duffy              /1/

  ManagerFirstName ManagerLastName
0            Terri           Duffy
1              Ken         Sánchez
```

**EDIT**

Since you can't update to pandas 0.14.1, load the results from pyodbc using [pandas.DataFrame.from_records](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html?highlight=from_records#pandas.DataFrame.from_records):

```
# get column names from pyodbc results
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=columns)
```

Comment: This does not work in pandas 0.14.0. I'm unable at present to upgrade to 0.14.1 to test there, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: @joeb1415 Updated on how to populate dataframe without using `read_sql`

Comment: Minor, you probably want to ``from_records(rows, columns=columns, coerce_float=True)`` so that you don't end up with stringed numeric columns, which is often the case with oracle/sql